# Running an external process to support an automated IntelliJ test

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, automated-tests

As a simple example, I have some tests which rely on a fresh (read "empty") local Redis instance.  My typical workflow has been to fire up the instance from the terminal and just restart or flushdb manually.

If possible, I'd love to wrap this up in the Run configuration of my tests.  The configuration dialog allows me to setup "Before launch" tasks, but these appear to run sequentially.  I really want something running in another process in the background that can be shut down at the end of the tests.

I have a few other external processes that I'd like to handle in a similar fashion.  I'm not sure the Run/Debug configuration is the right approach. I'm using Scala, and I'm open to other tools if they better suit the objective.  The end goal is to have as much as possible a single command that will fire up all the dependencies and shut them down at the end of the test run.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would implement a base class for these tests which spins-up Redis in a stage before running tests and then shuts it down after running tests.

For example in ScalaTest you would use the BeforeAndAfter trait:
http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.1/#org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter